# How to insert the first instruction to an empty basic block in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, bitcode

Inserting a new llvm instruction to a **non empty basic block**
is indeed pretty straight forward: simply iterate existing instructions
until you reach the desired place and use the

```
newInst->insertBefore(thatInst);
```

command. However, when I look at the `BasicBlock` interface [here](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html),
I can't seem to find **how to insert that first instruction?**
I mean when a fresh basic block has just been allocated and it is still empty, how does one insert the first instruction inside? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`IRBuilder`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html) like this:

```
llvm::IRBuilder builder(basicBlock);
builder.createAdd(...); // Replace "Add" as appropriate
```

Or, if you want to insert an already existing instruction object:

```
builder.insert(instruction);
```